# Create a file of numbers based on a file containing count of numbers (tally)

Tags: powershell, loops, csv, converters

I have a requirement to convert a .csv file containing data like this:

```
100,3
101,2
102,4
```

to a csv. file containing this:

```
100
100
100
101
101
102
102
102
102
```

I've written a macro in Excel that does this but the requirement is to carry this out against ~1 million records which crashes Excel.

Does anybody have a Powershell solution for this?

Comment: Does the CSV file have headers?

Comment: it doesn't - but it can if required :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the CSV does *not* contain headers, I'd do the following:

```
Import-Csv tally.txt -Header Number,Tally |ForEach-Object {
  ,$_.Number * $_.Tally
} |Set-Content output.txt
```

The expression `,"100" * "2"` will cause PowerShell to produce an array consisting of 2 copies of the string `"100"` - exactly the kind of expansion we want!